# How to use multiple form actions like input validation and input submission to servlet fron single form?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, jsp, servlets

```
 <script>
    function validateForm() 
    {
        var id = document.forms["myForm"]["id"].value;    
        if ( id % 1 != 0 )
        {
            alert("Id must be number");
            return false;
        }
        var name = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
        if ( name % 1 == 0 )
        {
            alert("Name must be in alphabets");
            return false;
        }
        var age = document.forms["myForm"]["age"].value;
        if ( age % 1 != 0 )
        {
            alert("Id must be number");
            return false;
        }
        var place = document.forms["myForm"]["place"].value;
        if ( place % 1 == 0 )
        {
            alert("place must be in alphabets");
            return false;
        }
        var choice = document.forms["myForm"]["choice"].value;
        if (choice % 1 != 0)
        {
            alert("Choice must be number");
            return false;
        }
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <form  action="ui" name="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get">
    <h2><p align="center"><b>User Management System</b></p></h2><br>
    <b>
    User ID : 
    <input type="text" name="id" required>  

    User Age : 
    <input type="text" name="age" required>  

    User Name :  
    <input type="text" name="name" required>  

    User Place :  
    <input type="text" name="place" required>   

    Enter your choice: 
    <input type="text" name="choice" required> 

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </b>
    </form><b>
```

I want to validate the inputs from user using Java script and also want to submit the inputs to the servlet name  called "ui" from this form. But validation is not taking place. Can anyone please guide me to perform both actions from the single form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a little spelling mistake.

```
<form  action="ui" name="myform" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get">
```

in the above line change `myform to myForm` and it will work.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer. Now it's working